# Apparent packet transfer --- inquiry [Q&A]

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm using EtherApe here. On occasion, these two nodes appear out of nowhere on my VPN connection. They appear beside each other every single time. It's always been the same one appearing every time. I believe they are attempting to receive packets. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lqgooLcBdaq1Cas1CrFN5yjnQMb-oeHq/view?usp=sharing) they are. And when [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZpOOSSQduIzGGIHQ13GlZOkUVTXyDXgr/view?usp=sharing) occurs (When the inst traffic becomes large enough to reach their nodes), they suddenly disappear.

I am 99% certain that these are the same attackers that were on my router & network previously. Any idea on how I can prevent them from communicating with my network interface's & device's traffic?